# AWX cannot find matching host

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, provisioning, awx

I have on premise AWX and inventory (instances on AWS). To provision newly launched instance I want to use [provisioning callbacks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#provisioning-callbacks).
But when executing this command from the instance

```
$ curl -v -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"host_config_key": "key1"}' https://my-host.com/api/v2/job_templates/28/callback/
```

an error occurs

```
{"msg":"No matching host could be found!"}
```

What might be wrong with AWX configuration if host is present within the dynamic inventory and `UPDATE ON LAUNCH` flag is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` extra header as allowed in settings and you should be good.

https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/8005